# Dynamically changing text by flipping through words

Tags: javascript, css

How do I make it so that on load an H1 dynamically flips through text.

Example;

1) Made for agencies...
2) Made for start-ups...
3) Made for small businesses...

And make it where every 2 seconds the words after "made for" change via Javascript.

Only issue is, only using Javascript and CSS, the HTML cannot change.

Thanks a ton!

Comment: Do you mean just fully replaces the text, or types it out?

Comment: Also - please post the HTML so we know the structure. :)

Comment: @JoelHager it types it out, so it would add a typing effect when replacing the words after Made for... agencies (deletes agencies after 2 seconds)... (typing effect) Start-ups (deletes start-ups after 2 seconds)... (typing effect) Businesses [LOOP]

As for the structure, here's a link: https://www.unstack.com/ (homepage, first section, H1)

Thank you so much!

Comment: Do you have the HTML that we can see? It's hard to know how to target the h1 without seeing the source.

Comment: We encourage users to not ask for ready solutions, but provide how they tried to solve their issue, with own effort. For what you are asking there are a dozen examples on codepen, so one of them can be adjusted and work for your case... Did you search for a solution? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Hey @Ron! I am actually a Customer Success Manager trying to go the extra mile for a web customer :) I'll check out codepen too!

Comment: @JoelHager sure thing! here's a link: https://codepen.io/chriscardone/pen/XWmRmyJ

Comment: You don't have any H1 elements declared in that HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `setInterval()` to set a predefined interval at which a function will be called and executed.

```js
var items = ['agencies', 'start-ups', 'small businesses'];
var itemCounter = 0;

setInterval(changeH1, 2000);   // set interval every 2 seconds to call a function

function changeH1() {   // function to perform changes to h1
  let h1 = document.getElementById('someH1');
  h1.innerHTML = "Made for " + items[itemCounter % items.length];
  itemCounter++;
}

changeH1();   // call it first so the h1 is populated immediately on load
```

```html
<h1 id="someH1"></>
```

Comment: He said he can't change the HTML, so there's no way of knowing how we can target the h1, whether it's the first h1 on the page, an id, a class, etc.

Comment: True... until he posts specific HTML this is just a general example, he can take it from here. If he wanted a more specific answer he should have asked a better question.

Comment: @Ivan86 here's the code https://codepen.io/chriscardone/pen/XWmRmyJ the way I was told to target it was using: var text= document.querySelector('section[data-id="~~SECTION ID~~"] h1');

Comment: @JoelHager here's the code codepen.io/chriscardone/pen/XWmRmyJ the way I was told to target it was using: var text= document.querySelector('section[data-id="~~SECTION ID~~"] h1'); thanks a ton everyone!

Comment: @ChrisCardone I don't see any  h1 elements in the codepen. What is the exact element you would like to target?

Comment: @Ivan86 sorry, it was an H3, I actually got your solution working: chriscardone.com thanks a ton!!